# Animating a map of ocean temperature

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have 12 subplots showing changes in ocean temperature for the Celtic Sea. Each subplot is for a different month in the year.

```
import xarray as xa
import cmocean.cm as cm
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import pycountry
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeat



# =============================================================================
#  Step 1: Get data
# =============================================================================
    
data_model = xa.open_dataset("PD_tavg_out_atlanticcentric.nc",decode_times = False)

sal_obs_data = xa.open_dataset("sal_obs_CS_all.nc",decode_times = False)
temp_obs_data = xa.open_dataset("temp_obs_CS_all.nc",decode_times = False)

data_obs = xa.merge([sal_obs_data,temp_obs_data])
data_obs = data_obs.rename(lon = "longitude",
                           lat = "latitude")

# =============================================================================
#  Step 2: Define Coordinates 
# =============================================================================
 
long_max = 122.4
long_min = 100.8
lat_max = 25.2
lat_min = 0
dep_max = 100
dep_min = 0
tim_max = 35406.0
tim_min = 35405.0 

def extract_shelf_sea(long_max, long_min, 
                      lat_max, lat_min,
                      dep_max, dep_min,
                      tim_max, tim_min):

# =============================================================================
#  Step 3: Extract data
# =============================================================================

    extract_model_data = data_model.sel(longitude = slice(long_min,long_max),
                                        latitude = slice(lat_min,lat_max),
                                        depth = slice(dep_min,dep_max),
                                        time = slice(tim_min,tim_max))
    
    
    extract_obs_data = data_obs.sel(time = data_obs.time,
                                    longitude = data_obs.longitude,
                                    latitude = data_obs.latitude,
                                    depth = extract_model_data.depth, method="nearest")
    
# =============================================================================
#  Step 4: Calculating the difference in salinity and temperature
# =============================================================================

    model_diff = extract_model_data.diff("depth")
    obs_diff = extract_obs_data.diff("depth")
    
    return model_diff, obs_diff


# =============================================================================
#  Step 5: Plotting
# =============================================================================

def plot_SCS():
    
    CS_model, CS_obs = extract_shelf_sea(2,-17,65,45,100,0,35405.95,35405)
    
    map_proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = -8.5, central_latitude = 55)

        
# =============================================================================
#     Observational Data (temperature)
# =============================================================================

    temp_obs = CS_obs.temp
    map_proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = -8.5, central_latitude = 55)
    plot = temp_obs.plot(cmap = cm.curl,
                         cbar_kwargs = {'label':'Change in temperature between 15m and 82m (°C)'},
                         col='time', col_wrap=4, 
                         transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                         subplot_kws={"projection":map_proj},
                         vmin=-6, vmax=6)
    plot.fig.suptitle("Celtic Sea - Observational Data")

    for ax, title in zip(plot.axes.flat, ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                                          'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']):
        ax.set_title(title)
    
    for ax in plot.axes.flat:
        ax.add_feature(cfeat.LAND,zorder=100,edgecolor="k",facecolor="gray")
```

[image]
I'd like to animate this, so I only have a single plot, but every second or so it moves to the next month. I've tried a few things with plotly and the matplotlib animation and haven't had any success.

I don't even really know what else to try. Any advice helpful!
Sorry, I can't attach the full original dataset as it's a huge file.

Comment: Can you try using https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/hyperslicer.html#Hyperslicer-with-Xarray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is excellent for the use of [`ArtistAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/dynamic_image.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-dynamic-image-py),  i.e., the flipbook approach using precomputed images. Sample code because the format of your animation is not specified:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=6, nrows=3, figsize=(15, 10))
#get specs for large image
gs = axes[0, -2].get_gridspec()

#remove unnecessary axis objects
for ax in axes[0:, -2:].flat: 
    ax.remove()
  
#update axes list and label all static images
axes = fig.get_axes()
for i, ax in enumerate(axes): 
    ax.axis("off")
    ax.set_title(f"month {i+1}")

#add axis object for large, animated image
ax_large = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:, -2:])
ax_large.axis("off")

#fake images
def f(x, y, i):
    return np.sin(x*i/4) * i/6 + np.cos(y* (12-i)/4) 

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 80)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120).reshape(-1, 1)

all_ims = []
min_v = -3
max_v = 3
ani_cmap = "seismic"

for i, ax_small in enumerate(axes):
    #image generation unnecessary for you because your images already exist
    arr = f(x, y, i)
    #static image into small frame
    im_small = ax_small.imshow(arr, vmin=min_v, vmax=max_v, cmap=ani_cmap)
    #animated image into large frame
    im_large = ax_large.imshow(arr, animated=True, vmin=min_v, vmax=max_v, cmap=ani_cmap)
    #animated images are collected in a list
    all_ims.append([im_large])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, all_ims, interval=200, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]